# Why does this Python code break with Tornado 4?

Tags: python, closures, scope, tornado

This code snippet is OK with Tornado 3.2, but throws an exception in Tornado 4.
(The code is an extracted and simplified version of a complex code.)
(Tested with python 2.7.6)

```
from tornado import gen
from tornado.ioloop import IOLoop


@gen.engine
def foo():

    @gen.Task
    def bar(callback=None):
        print bar
        callback(None)

    yield bar
    ioloop.stop()

ioloop = IOLoop.current()
ioloop.add_callback(foo)
ioloop.start()
```

In Tornado 4, this fails with this exception:

```
...
  File "/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 160, in wrapper
    result = func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "temp.py", line 9, in bar
    print bar
NameError: free variable 'bar' referenced before assignment in enclosing scope
```

I think management of closure variables is a task of the interpreter. Why does Tornado affect this?

Comment: If we move `bar` to global scope, this exception is raised: `NameError: global name 'bar' is not defined`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`gen.Task` is not a decorator; it should be used with `yield gen.Task(bar)` instead.

The change in behavior you are seeing is that in Tornado 4.0 `Task()` calls its argument immediately, while in older versions the function was not called until the task was yielded. Decorators are applied before the name is bound, so the function cannot see itself when Task is used as a decorator.